# How to calculate the specified coordinate of a curve path in a 3D space?

Tags: math, 3d

this is my first question here.

Let's say I have an 3D object facing to somewhere at starts, and it is keep rotating and moving forward to where it facing constantly. It has given the start position, speed, the angle it facing at start, and the angle it facing after a time point. How can I calculate the coordinates at any time point I specified?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have constant forward speed and constant rotational speed, with rotational axis fixed with respect to the object, then your object will be describing a circle. The speed tells you the path length per unit of time, which in this case is an arc length, and the rotational speed tells you the change in angle per unit of time. Combining these two you can compute the radius of the circle, since arc length is angle times radius. The center of the circle, relative to the object, will be in the plane orthogonal to the axis of rotation, and also always orthogonal to the tangential forward direction.